# Sessions not ending correctly

Tags: php, session, logging, authentication, logout

I've created a simple log in system for my website, as I want to restrict access to some of the pages. The users can log in in fine, however I am having problems with the logging users out. I'm using `$_SESSION['username']` to store the username.

When I log the user out it appears to log out the user and shows the log in screen, however when i go to a one of the restricted pages the session is still active. When I then try to log in with a different user, the log in page shows that a different user is logged in but the restricted pages still show the old user as being logged in.

This is my log out page

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['username']);
session_destroy();
header('Location: sign_up.php');
?>
```

This checks if a user is logged in for the log in page.

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    include "logged_in_bar.php";
    //if session is equal to 1, display logged in bar
} else {
    include "login_bar.php";
    //if seesion is not equal to 1, display log in bar
}
?>
```

for the other pages I use

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    execute this
} else {
    header ('Location: sign_up.php');
}
```

I do have `session_start();` at the top of all my pages.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: are you using a custom session_save_handler?

Comment: No I'm not, should I be. Still quite new with php.

Comment: Are you using `session_name()` anywhere as that can create a second session. I would also suggest `var_dump($_SESSION)` to see what is actually in there

Comment: not using session_name() anywhere. I am sending the session data to a database if that would make any difference?

Comment: I added session_destroy to one of the pages not working properly, and when I visited it I needed to refresh the page before teh session was destroyed anyone know why this would happen?

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();

$_SESSION = array();

if (ini_get('session.use_cookies')) {
  setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000);
}

session_destroy();
```

Comment: I'm just using sessions not cookies, I set it by $_SESSION["username"]=$username;

Comment: In your above comments, you say you are sending the session data to a database, and also say you are not calling session_set_save_handler.  In what manner are you sending the data to the db?  Also did you verify the use_cookies setting is not set to true? ini_get('session.use_cookies')

Comment: did you try calling this to clear all session variables: $_SESSION = array();

Comment: I use a form to submit the data and use a hidden input to assign the input value. This is then submitted to another page where I use a normal sql query to input the data to the database, looking at the cookie setting now